Help me calculate the assumed interest rate $i'$ under $\frac{\bar{A}_x}{\mu_x}=\bar{a'}_x \neq \bar{a}_x$
Setup

force of mortality $\mu_x = 0.005\cdot (1.01)^x$

original assumed interest rate $i = 0.05$

assumption:
$$
\frac{\bar{A}_x}{\mu_x}=\bar{a'}_x (\neq \bar{a}_x)
$$


At this point, we want to find $i'(\neq i)$.
My try
$$
\bar{A}_x = 1- \delta \bar{a}_x,\ \delta = \log(1.05),\ \delta'=\log(1+i'),\\
_tp_x = \exp\left\{-\frac{0.005\cdot(1.01)^x}{\log(1.01)}\left((1.01)^t-1\right)\right\}
$$
Then, we get
\begin{align}
1-\delta \bar{a}_x&=\mu_x \bar{a'}_x\\
\therefore\ 1 - \delta \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\delta t \right)\ _tp_xdt&=0.005\cdot (1.01)^x\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\delta' t\right)\ _tp_xdt
\end{align}
How should this equation be solved?
